# convert column values to row after particular match in linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed, scripting

I have a file in which values are all in 1 column in repetitive mode (1 set of values comes after say 10 row) . now i want to put this set of values from column to row (set wise) in repetitive mode. Showing some example as below

```
A = 1  
B = 2
C = 3
-----
A = 4
B = 5
C = 6
```

here i want output like below

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

Can anyone please help me in solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say

```
awk '/^-----/ { print line; line = ""; sep = ""; next } { line = line sep $3; sep = "," } END { print line }' filename
```

This works as follows:

```
/^-----/ {               # If the current line is a delimiter
  print line             # print the stuff we just constructed (see below)
  line = ""              # reset state variables
  sep = ""
  next                   # do nothing else
}
{                        # otherwise:
  line = line sep $3     # append 3rd field of the current line to the output
  sep = ","              # <-- the first time around, sep is "", so there's no
                         #     comma before the first field in the output.
}
END {                    # When the input ends:
  print line             # print the last record.
}
```

Comment: there are some values which are space separated , so $4 $5values are not getting include in final output..any idea how include that also?

Comment: You could use `sub(/^[^=]*= */, ""); line = line sep $0;` instead of `line = line sep $3;`, for example; that'll remove everything up to the first `=` (and spaces following it), then use the rest of the line as a token. You might want to remove spaces from the end of the line as well if you go that route (e.g. `sub(/ *$/, "");`).

Answer (score 0):

Line of same serie with separator (like in sample)

```
sed '/^---/ b treat
     s/[[:blank:]]\{1,\}//g;H;$!d
:treat
     s/.*//;x
     s/\n[^=]*=/,/g;s/,//
     ' YourFile
```

Assuming:

- there is only digit as value
- there is always a correct serie length (not feed with empty value is pe: `B=` is missing)